# Password protecting submit button on MS Access form still results in button submission

Tags: ms-access, forms, vba, password-protection, ms-access-2003

I'm trying to password protect a submit button on a form I'm building in Microsoft Access 2003. The button, when clicked, will add a new record to my database. The idea of the password protection is that when the user clicks the button, a prompt will appear asking for a password. They can either enter the password and click OK to proceed with verifying it has been entered properly, or they can click Cancel and close the prompt window (after which they will receive an confirmation alert). If the password matches what is hardcoded, the record will be added. If the password is not a match, an error message will display.

This should be easy enough. However, the record will ALWAYS be added to the database, no matter if the password is entered incorrectly, no password is entered, or the user cancels out of the password window. What am I doing wrong with the below code?

```
Private Sub AddLeadServerButton_Click()
    Dim strPasswd

    strPasswd = InputBox("Enter Password", "Restricted Form")

    'Check to see if there is any entry made to input box, or if
    'cancel button is pressed. If no entry made then exit sub.

    If strPasswd = "" Or strPasswd = Empty Then
        MsgBox "No Input Provided", vbInformation, "Required Data"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'If correct password is entered open Employees form
    'If incorrect password entered give message and exit sub

    If strPasswd = "thepassword" Then
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
        Me.Parent!NewInstallation.Form!InstallationLeadServerComboBox.Requery
        Me.Parent!NewReport.Form!LeadServerFilterComboBox.Requery
    Else
        MsgBox "Sorry, you do not have access to this form", _
               vbOKOnly, "Important Information"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You do realize that anybody with enough smarts will be able to look at your code (or the compiled MDE/ACCDE) and figure out the password for themselves, right?

Comment: Yes, but it's not so much confidentiality of the information that I'm worried about, it's just making it inconvenient for someone on our team at work to add a record, to the point that them needing a password will let them know they shouldn't be doing so. It also doesn't help that I don't know much about Access.

Comment: Why not just check their logon name and restrict it for people you don't want adding records?

Comment: The overhead of maintaining a list of people allowed to access the file is prohibitive, but if you would recommend that above either of the other answers, I'd accept that as the solution.

Comment: You don't need to maintain a list. If there's an NTFS security group with the members in it, then you can check their membership there. How many people are we talking about who should be given access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish the behavior you want, you will have to set the form to prevent new records from being added.  Then, ask the user for the password, set the form back to enable adding new records, and move to the new record.

1. If the property sheet is not
   displayed, on the View menu, click
   Properties to display the form's
   property sheet.
2. In the Form property sheet, click
   the Data tab, and then set the
   `AllowAdditions` property to No.
3. Add a command button to the
   form. Set the command
   button's `OnClick` property to [Event
   Procedure], and then click the Build
   button to the right of the OnClick
   property box.  Type the following
   statement in the `Form_Customers`
   module:

   ```
   Forms!Customers.AllowAdditions = True
   ```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208586

I don't recommend checking for the password after the user has already entered data.  It gets frustrating when you fill out a form, only to find out at the end that you don't have rights to save your work.

Comment: This solution seemed like it would work just fine. What I've decided to do instead is just create an "Admin" User/Group Account that requires a password when you initially open the file. I will instruct anyone who should be cleared to modify the DB to use this logon ID and the password I set for it.

Answer (score 1):

Hook the `BeforeInsert` event on your form, and add the password check there.  You can set `Cancel=True` if they don't provide the correct password, and that will cause the addition of the record to be abandoned.

Example:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
    If MsgBox("Insert new record here?", _
        vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I should probably mention that this form has 2 ComboBoxes that you select values from, as well as the submit button. Adding the code above results in the "Insert new record here" prompt each time you select a value from either list. Ideally, the prompt should only appear when you click "submit".

Comment: Unfortunately, the record gets inserted when the first character is typed into the first field of the empty form.  That's just the way Access works.  If you want to override that behavior, you have to insert the record yourself; it's not that hard to do.  I will add another answer with that technique.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using bound forms where you can, this will give you greater control over your data with a little extra work, the best way to think of it is addressesing your data from opposite ends.

Bound forms are very much about telling the database to prevent updates that you don't wish to make whereas unbound forms are more about not making any changes until you are absolutely happy.

Just a personal preference but I think unbound are worth the time and effort.